# Expectation and Variance of Sum of dependent discrete variables

Tags: variance, conditional-expectation, bernoulli-distribution

Q. Let X be a discrete random variable such that X = 0 with probability 0.5 and X = 1 with probability 0.5. Let Y be a discrete random variable such that Y = 1 when X = 1 and Y = 0 when X = 0. What is the mean and variance of X + Y?

My Sol:
$$E(X+Y) = E(X) + E(Y) = 0.5 + [\Sigma yp(y|x)] = 0.5 + [0.p(y=0|x=0)+0.p(y=0|x=1)+1.p(y=1|x=0)+1.p(y=1|x=1)]= 0.5 + 0.5 = 1$$

$$Var(X+Y) = Var(X)+Var(Y)+2cov(X,Y)=??$$

I am not sure if my current thinking is correct, I would appreciate any help.

Comment: so, is X=Y then?

Comment: It looks like Y is dependent on X's value? I don't think  they are equal?

Comment: Can Y be another value than 0 or 1? Or is there a situation where X is not equal to Y?

Comment: You do seem to have $Y=X$ so $X+Y=2X$  with probability $1$, $E[X+Y]=E[X]+E[Y]=\frac12+\frac12=1=2E[X]$ and $Var(X+Y)=Var(X)+Var(Y)+2Cov(X,Y)=\frac14+\frac14+2 \times \frac14=1=4Var(X)$

Comment: Y can only be 0 or 1 @gunes

Comment: what if question was Y=1 when X=0 and Y=0 when X=1? Is the answer the same? @Henry

Comment: @eunji In that case $X+Y=1$ with probability $1$, i.e. constant.  The mean and variance should be obvious and $Cov(X,Y)=-\frac14$